# Complex XML parsing with Perl and LIBXML

Tags: perl, libxml2

I have XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataCollection.xsl"?>

<measCollecFile xmlns="">
    <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.435 V7.2.0">
    </fileHeader>

    <measData>
        <managedElement localDn="bs=8" swVersion="R21A"/>

        <measInfo measInfoId="CORE,SIP_session_statistics">
            <measType p="1">CPUUSAGE</measType>
            <measType p="2">CPUMEM</measType>
            <measType p="3">SYSMEM</measType>

            <measValue measObjLdn="SGC.bsNo=17,networkRole=2">
                <r p="1">10</r>
                <r p="2">20</r>
                <r p="3">30</r>
            </measValue>

            <measValue measObjLdn="SGC.bsNo=18,networkRole=2">
                <r p="1">40</r>
                <r p="2">50</r>
                <r p="3">60</r>
            </measValue>
        </measInfo>
    </measData>
</measCollecFile>
```

QUESTION:

I want to extract the `40` from  `<r p="1">40</r>` element. The only thing given is `<measType p="1">CPUUSAGE</measType>` and `<measValue measObjLdn="SGC.bsNo=18,networkRole=2">`
i.e. I only know that I need to find the `CPUUSAGE` of the `bsNo=18`. The order of the data is always maintained.

---

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
my $qry="//measInfo[measType/text() = 'CPUUSAGE']/measValue";

my @nodes= $conn->findnodes($qry);

foreach my $vnode (@nodes) {
    if ($vnode->getAttribute('measObjLdn') =~ /'bsNo=18'/) {
        foreach my $node ($vnode) {
            foreach my $p ($node->getChildnodes) {
                if (ref($p)=~'Element'){
                    $no=$p->textContent; 
                    print $no;**#this prints the value of all the <r> elements**
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My challenge is there can be many elements like CPUUSAGE,CPUMEM... and how I can reach the correct order in the `<r>` element in that order for a given `measValue` attribute (`/'bsNo=18'/`).

And subsequently modify that 40 to some other desired value**

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is difficult to do with a single XPath query, but the solution to this problem is by no means complicated.

Comment: @amon, `/measCollecFile/measData/measInfo/measValue[ @measObjLdn="SGC.bsNo=18,networkRole=2" ]/r[ @p = ../../measType[text()="CPUUSAGE"]/@p ]`

Comment: Catch: That causes `../../measType[text()="CPUUSAGE"]` to be performed for each `r` when it only needs to be performed once.

Comment: thanks friend! but the CPUUSAGE can appear as the first or the second in any position. How do you catch the corresponding <r> element in that order.

Comment: Why do you think the XPath I posted cares about position? There are no numbers in it!

Comment: 1) You need to find the `measType` element whose text is `CPUUSAGE` to get the value of its `p` attribute. 2) Then you find the `measValue` element whose `measObjLdn` is `SGC.bsNo=18,networkRole=2`. 3) Then you find the child `r` whose `p` attribute is the one found earlier.

Comment: I know Xpath does not care. But this is the requirement to get the right <r> element for CPUUSAGE value.

Comment: ok I get what u mean. I will try now in this case.  There is another XML where the P attribute is missing and the corresponding P is also missing the <r> element its only the order in which they appear represents the correct values. Hence my question.

Comment: Also. I need to modify the 40 to some other value like 50 or so. thanks in advance.

Comment: Another point @measObjLdn="SGC.bsNo=18,networkRole=2" This complete attrinute is not provided. Only the bsNo=18 is provided. Which is just part of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your Perl code can't work because you match the attribute value against `'bsNo=18'` including single quotes.

If you want to find the `r` element with the same `p` attribute as the `CPUUSAGE` node, you could either try the single XPath expression by ikegami or something like the following:

```
for my $type_node ($conn->findnodes('//measInfo/measType[.="CPUUSAGE"]')) {
    my $p = $type_node->getAttribute('p');
    my $qry = <<"EOF";
..
/measValue[contains(concat(\@measObjLdn, ','), 'bsNo=18,')]
/r[\@p='$p']
EOF

    for my $r_node ($type_node->findnodes($qry)) {
        print $r_node->textContent, "\n";
    }    
}
```

This first loops over all `measType` nodes whose content is `CPUUSAGE`, gets the `p` attribute then finds all the corresponding `r` nodes. This approach should be more efficient than a single XPath query.

To find the `r` node by position and modify its contents, try:

```
for my $type_node ($conn->findnodes('//measInfo/measType[.="CPUUSAGE"]')) {
    my $pos = $type_node->findvalue('count(preceding-sibling::measType) + 1');
    my $qry = <<"EOF";
..
/measValue[contains(concat(\@measObjLdn, ','), 'bsNo=18,')]
/r[$pos]
EOF

    for my $r_node ($type_node->findnodes($qry)) {
        $r_node->removeChildNodes;
        $r_node->appendText('50');
    }
}

print $conn->toString;
```

Comment: nwellnhof! this is very helpful.

Comment: in case the element names are variables then I am not able to find the nodes. like //$measInfo/$measType[.="$CPUUSAGE"]. Also when I am trying to do exact match instead of contains then as well its not finding nodes. thanks in advance.